# Is using a boost void allocator bad practice?

Tags: c++, boost, allocator, boost-interprocess

I have seen sometimes people use a generic void allocator defined like this :

```
using namespace boost::interprocess;
typedef allocator<void, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> VoidAllocator;
```

Is it considered a bad practice ? I found that std::allocator is depreciated, should I be concerned about the boost version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is bad practice, but mostly a useless practice.

An `allocator` of `void` cannot allocate anything and doesn't have any useful trait.
So at the end it is only useful for rebinding. 
And if you are rebinding, you can actually replace `void` by `char` anyway.

Maybe there is a "symmetry" argument to have a `void` allocator, but it creates confusion since there are not `reference`, `size_type` or other typical trait members.

(The idea of rebinding allocators is odd in the first place, probably a remnant of old language limitations. Allocators shouldn't need to know the type they are allocating, because is at best redundant and at worst the container usually rebinds to the type it really needs anyway --e.g. node types--.)

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. My [randomDataType] is expecting an allocator that isn't void. If it receives one, it rebinds it to the one expected and works as well as it can. Void allocator is useless on compile time to define data structures but helpful on runtime by rebinding. Well, that is if I understood properly.

Comment: I agree that it is odd to have to specify the type redundantly. Reading `AllocatorType1 allocatorName1(shMemSegment.get_segment_manager());` `AllocatorType2 allocatorName2(shMemSegment.get_segment_manager());` `AllocatorType3 allocatorName3(shMemSegment.get_segment_manager());` [...] annoys me a lot and seems completely unnecessary. (That was what motivated the question)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the reasons that `std::allocator<void>` is now disfavoured also apply to other things that allege to be "allocators of void".

According to [p0174r0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0174r0#2.4)

> Similarly, `std::allocator<void>` is defined so that various template
>   rebinding tricks could work in the original C++98 library, but it is
>   not an actual allocator, as it lacks both `allocate` and `deallocate`
>   member functions, which cannot be synthesized by default from
>   `allocator_traits`. That need went away with C++11 and the
>   `void_pointer` and `const_void_pointer` type aliases in
>   `allocator_traits`. However, we continue to specify it in order to
>   avoid breaking old code that has not yet been upgraded to support
>   generic allocators, per C++11.

You can just as easily define a template alias.

```
using namespace boost::interprocess;
template <typename T>
using segment_allocator = allocator<T, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>;
```

Comment: I will try to use that template trick that looks like a more graceful way to deal with the situation, thanks :)